# Filter a list of maps from an Atom in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm developing a mini-social media API where the user is allowed to insert a new profile, connect two profiles together (like friends) and then receive recommendations based on the "friends of my friends" rule.

Right now I'm trying to create the API for Profile.

I have an atom that holds a list of maps, one for each profile.

```
(def profiles (atom ()))

(defn create [request]
 (swap! profiles conj {:id (get-in request [:body "id"])
                    :name (get-in request [:body "name"])
                    :age (get-in request [:body "age"])
                    :recommendable (get-in request [:body "recommendable"])
                    :friends (list) 
})
(created "")
)
```

I was trying to develop the find-by-id for the GET http verb for the API when I stumbled into a problem. How can I get the values from the maps within said list so I can apply functions to it?

For instance, here I was trying to use the filter function to return me only the maps that contained a given id. But I keep getting an error:

```
(defn find-by-id [id]
  (filter #(= (:id %) id) profiles)
)

Dont know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Atom
```

It seems to me that filter is not applicable to an Atom.

Same thing happens to remove:

```
(defn delete-by-id [id]
 (swap! profiles (remove #(= (:id %) id) profiles))
)
```

When I try with @profiles I get an empty array as a result. And to make things worst when I tried the filter function using REPL it worked just fine.

Which leaves me wondering what am I missing here.

Could anyone please tell me what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first one fails because, as it says, atoms aren't a sequence, which `filter` is expecting.

You need to get the sequence out of the atom before you can `filter` it:

```
; I'm dereferencing the atom using @ to get the list of profiles that it holds
(defn find-by-id [id]
  (filter #(= (:id %) id) @profiles))
```

Note though, this isn't optimal. You're relying on the state of `profiles` that can change at seemingly random times (if you have asynchronous processes `swap!`ping it). It may complicate debugging since you can't get a good handle on the data before it's passed to `filter`. It also isn't good for the function to rely on `profiles` being an atom, since that's irrelevant to its function, and you may change your design later. It would be more future proof to make this function rely purely on its parameters and have no knowledge of the atom:

```
(defn find-by-id [id profiles]
  (filter #(= (:id %) id) profiles))

; Then call it like this. I renamed your atom here
(find-by-id some-id @profile-atom)
```

---

Your second example fails because `swap!` accepts a function as its second argument. I think you meant to use `reset!`, which changes the value of the atom regardless of what it was before:

```
(defn delete-by-id [id]
  (reset! profiles (remove #(= (:id %) id) @profiles)))
```

Although, this isn't optimal either. If you want to update an atom based on a previous state, use `swap!` instead and supply an updating function:

```
(defn delete-by-id [id]
  (swap! profile-atom (fn [profiles] (remove #(= (:id %) id)) profiles)))
```

Or, slightly more succinctly:

```
(defn delete-by-id [id]
  (swap! profile-atom (partial remove #(= (:id %) id))))
```

I'm partially applying `remove` to make a function. The old state of the atom is passed as the last argument to `remove`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But the find-by-id keeps giving me no result at all. And the delete is not removing the map from the list. Also, you recommended that I turn the profile list into a parameter to my functions, but since this is an API my handler.clj file only has the routes and the whole code is inside a profile.clj file. If I were to pass the profiles as an argument where would I declare it? Since leaving it inside profile.clj would make it inacessible inside handler.clj, and if it's the other way around my create function wouldn't be able to update the profile list.

Comment: @LeonardoMarinho For the filtering and removing not working, the ID must be something other than what you're searching for. You'll need to double check the ID you're passing vs the ID that's in the map. For the second problem, you could just wrap it in another function. Something like `(fn [profile-atom] (find-by-id some-id @profile-atom)))`. I'm not sure if that answers your question.